# is slope of line of best fit through points the same as y intercept of regression through their derivatives

Tags: derivatives, linear-regression

I'm struggling to do proof I'm trying to validate for a decision on how I calculation erosion rates. It is computationally much more efficient for me to calculate erosion month to month, than it is to redo a regression of shoreline regression every month (assuming monthly data).

In the top graph, I plot shoreline position against some time t_n. A regression through these points will have some slope which is the erosion rate of that part of a shoreline. In the following image, I instead take the slope point to point, and fit a regression through that. I would prefer to do this, as calculating the shoreline position against some time t_n means that every month I get new data, I have to recalculate the shoreline position against that point for every month, versus calculating one additional data point, and finding its average.

[image]

I added the limit to the bottom function to stress the point that in a situation of erosion occurring around a particular rate, the m value should be 0 in that equation.

Logically, this makes sense to me... when I'm trying to write a proof for this, I really don't know where to begin.

Is it enough to simply say

y = mx + b

dy/dx = m --> the constant of the regression fit on the individual slopes?

If it isn't the same, it could be due to optimizing against the error in shoreline position versus optimizing the error of the rate itself, maybe proving that is the same (or isn't) is sufficient?

Comment: Applying a regression is not very time consuming. And testing if $m=0$ or $m\neq 0$ is also possible (t-test).

Comment: If I correctly understand, you are asking if the coefficient m of the fitting mx+b can be determined by simply averaging the finite differences (which approximate the derivatives). Well, it depends on which fit you have in mind. Least squares?

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli yes - least squares. And yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do :)

Applying a regression is not time consuming.. but analyzing satellite imagery to calculate the points the regression is.

Comment: @NickBrady The more context you post, the better are the answers/comments. If you are too vague, then you will get an answer, but probably not a good/helpful answer. Just an advice.

Comment: @callculus42 thank you, added additional context.

Comment: I'm very confused about what your difficulty is. You have a sequence of images. Somehow you're able to calibrate these images so that you can measure the position of the shoreline in meters. You have a growing set of data of this kind. Software to do a linear regression is widely available. So each time you get a new data point, add it to the data set and re-run the linear regression. Why do you need to do something different?

Comment: @DavidK This is starting to get a little beyond the question, which I believe was answered.. trying to understand it still... but in theory yes that is true. I could pick a reference point, and make everything relative to that reference point and just tack on additional points. In practice, many shorelines erode sufficiently that the reference must be restarted, and it is simpler as a whole to always make the most recent month the reference point. I'm sure there are things I could do to optimize this, but for now, thats what I'm doing.

Comment: If your reference point disappears, how can you align the latest satellite imagery with the previous month in order to tell how far the shoreline moved? I think you may have a confused idea of what a "reference point" is. As for the accepted answer, did you notice where it says "this evaluation is less precise"? That says to me, "**Don't do that.**" If a paper with your methodology were submitted for publication and I were a reviewer, I would recommend that it not be published.

Comment: Thanks for your input @DavidK. I did understand that, and so I have marked it as the accepted answer and am grateful for Doriano's help.

Comment: I don't object to accepting the answer (some people like to wait 24 hours before accepting, but it's a perfectly fine answer and I don't know what could be added to it). What puzzled me is why you apparently choose to continue using the difference method despite what the answer said about it.

Comment: I am NOT using the later method I hoped to compare the first case to, per Doriano's answer. His answer informed my decision. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us start with the least squares fit. We want to minimize
$$ \chi^2 = \sum_j \left(y_j - m x_j -b\right)^2 $$

The result is:
$$ m = \frac{\sum_j y_j \sum_j x_j- \sum_j y_j x_j }{\left(\sum_j x_j\right)^2 - \sum_j x_j^2 \sum_j 1}  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,    (1)$$

This is different from the average of the finite differences:
$$
m' = \frac{\sum_j \frac{y_{j+1}-y_j}{x_{j+1} - x_j} }{n}
$$

It is particularly easy to see this if the $x_j$ are equally spaced:
$$
m' = \frac{\frac{\sum_j \left( y_{j+1}-y_j\right)}{x_2 - x_1} }{n}
$$
Calculating the sum:
$$
m' = \frac{y_n-y_1}{n\left(x_2 - x_1\right)} = \frac{y_n-y_1}{x_n - x_1}
$$
This $m'$ only depends on the first and last values of $y_j$. Intuitively, this evaluation is less precise than the evaluation through Eq. 1, which takes into consideration the whole set of data.